# Invalid number of paramters with xcopy

Tags: command, command-prompt, xcopy

I am using the command below:

```sh
C:\>xcopy /i /e %IDF_PATH%\examples\get-started\hello_world F:\Projekt1\Eclipse_kodok
```

The problem is every time I get the error:

> Invalid number of parameters

Is there any method to solve this problem?

(I'm a beginner command prompt user.)

Comment: It helps to include the error message you get.

Comment: The error is no more or less than Invalid number of parameters. That's it.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651776/xcopy-returns-error-invalid-number-of-parameters-when-exclude-parameter-is-set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcopy returns error "Invalid number of parameters" when exclude parameter is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651776/xcopy-returns-error-invalid-number-of-parameters-when-exclude-parameter-is-set)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try including source and destination in quotes (it is likely that %IDF_PATH% contains spaces).

Second, if the destination is a directory, use the backslash at the end.

like this:

```
xcopy /i /e "%IDF_PATH%\examples\get-started\hello_world" "F:\Projekt1\Eclipse_kodok\"
```

If the destination is a file, try to use this undocumented feature of xcopy:

```
xcopy /i /e "%IDF_PATH%\examples\get-started\hello_world" "F:\Projekt1\Eclipse_kodok*"
```

Hope this helps :-)